# React and TypeScript - how to import Less

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to import LESS classes inside my ReactJS component.

I'm using `react-autosuggest` and according to documentation (for JS) i should do it like this:

```
//file: myTheme.css

.container { ... }
.input { ... }
.suggestionsContainer { ... }
.suggestion { ... }
.suggestionFocused { ... }
```

and then, in my component import it and use like this:

```
import theme from 'theme.css';
// ...
<Autosuggest theme={theme} ... />
```

The problem is, that TypeScript does not allow me to import css file like this. It says:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../Stylesheets/AutosuggestStyles.css'`

Another problem is that I would like to use `Less` for styling my components. I have no idea how should I do that.

How can I do that (if not able to do with Less, CSS is enough for me)

Comment: Css can not be simply imported, it's not typescript nor javascript. You need to change the class names of your elements to match the css classes (the css files should be loaded in the html). There are some tools which let you do things like that, but it's not supported out of the box. For example: [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) and [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do that

Just declare it in a file `globals.d.ts`

```
declare module "theme.css";
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

We use typed-css-modules-loader for webpack.
It generates d.ts typings by watcher.

1. npm install less-loader style-loader css-loader typed-css-modules-loader --save-dev
2. Add to webpack.config, to rules section (if you're using Webpack 2)

   ```
   {
   test: /\.less$/,
   include: jsDir,
   exclude: commonExcludePaths,
   use: [
       'style-loader',
       'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=\'[path][name]-[local]--[hash:base64:5]\'',
       'typed-css-modules-loader',
   ]}
   ```

Sometimes TS compiler doesn't see new typings, you need wait or re-run your watcher.
Hope this helps