# How to require/import .less file in typescript file

Tags: typescript, less, webpack-2

I am trying to import a `.less` file in `.ts` file but I am not able to do that.
I am using webpack2 as bundler & webstorm IDE

Here snippet for less loader in a webpack.config.js file

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,      //less loader
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
    //loader: 'css-loader!less-loader'
    loader: 'raw-loader!less-loader'
  })
}, {
  test: /\.ts$/,    //typescript loader
  //include: path.resolve(__dirname, "ts-src"),
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, "js"),
  loader: "ts-loader"
}
//rest of code
resolve: {
  extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".css", ".less"],
}
```

As mentioned in [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434995/react-and-typescript-how-to-import-less) I tried by creating a global.d.ts file but no luck

Also i tried to `require` the file in the `main.ts` but in this case I am not seeing any option to requires a less file.
My question is how to load a `.less` file in a typescript files

[[image: Project strucure]

Comment: If you just want to include the `less` file in your app, you can do `import <path>/style.less`. Webpack will then include (and parse) the file in your bundle. Just because your IDE doesn't autocomplete the path for you, doesn't mean it doesn work.

Comment: @SebastianSebald i tried that. The problem is ts file is not recognizing the .less file,If I import in that way, build/compilation is failing

Answer (score 1):

Though I could not find out how to include `.less` in `ts` files but I found an way around by creating a javascript file and importing less in it

**import.js**

```
import "./../styles/main.less";
```

Have created a config file to resolve the paths to be used in `CommonsChunkPlugin`

**entryConfig.js**

```
module.exports={
    // rest of code
    style:'./js/import.js'
}
```

In webpack.config.js

```
entry: {
  //rest of code
  style: entryConfig.style
},

//rest of code

new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common',
    filename: 'common-[hash].js',
    chunk: ['common', 'home','style']
})
```

where string `style` is same as the key name in entry object

Answer (score -1):

If your style.less file is in root of project, src folder you can use it as follows.

```
import "style.less";
```

webpack.config.js should have properly configured style-loader and less-loader as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/wiki/Webpack-config)
I have it like this:

```
module: {
   rules: [
      ...
      { test: /\.less$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'], issuer: /\.[tj]s$/i},
      { test: /\.less$/i, use: ['css-loader', 'less-loader'], issuer: /\.html?$/i },
   ]
}
```

I have two, one for imports in ts/js files, the other one is for require in html templates

```
<require from="style.less"></require>
```